# PHP error trying to insert on database GET Method

Tags: php, android, mysql, get

I have a problem with my PHP when I'm trying to insert two values on a database.

I am using Android and I call the php to make the insert. I post my Android code:

```
 private void loadPhase() {
    String url = "http://www.myurl.com/scriptsfolder/myphptoinsertranking.php?id=prueba0101&points=200";

    if (numQuestion < 11) {
        header4questions.setText(listQuestions.get(questionPosition));

        answer1.setText(listAnswers.get(questionPosition * 4));
        answer2.setText(listAnswers.get((questionPosition * 4) + 1));
        answer3.setText(listAnswers.get((questionPosition * 4) + 2));
        answer4.setText(listAnswers.get((questionPosition * 4) + 3));

        if(numQuestion % 5 == 0 && numQuestion > 0)
        {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.aplausos);
            mp.start();
        }

        numQuestion++;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have finished the quiz!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Intent inn1 = getIntent();
                        inn1 = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(inn1);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "INSERT ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Intent inn1 = getIntent();
                        inn1 = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(inn1);
                    }
                }) {

        };

        //Adding the string request to the queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

I post also my php code:

```
<?php
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
$id = $_POST['id'];
$points = $_POST['points'];

$con = mysqli_connect("server.com:1111","username","userpassword","databasename");
if (!$con->connect_error) 
{
    $sql= "INSERT INTO table (IdUser, Points) values ('$id','$points')"; 

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo "Successfully Registered";
    }
    else{
        echo "Could not register"; 
    }
}
else{
    echo 'error de conexion';
}
}
?>
```

The result that I have is: "Could not register". Even if I try to do it with the Android code or going to the URL on the explorer.

But, when I do the insert on phpmyadmin I have no errors and it works correctly.

I don't know why it doesn't make the insert, can anyone helps me, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: USE `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are making a GET request while checking POST , change the code of php to this

```
<?php
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
$id = $_GET['id'];
$points = $_GET['points'];

$con = mysqli_connect("server.com:1111","username","userpassword","databasename");
if (!$con->connect_error) 
{
    $sql= "INSERT INTO table (IdUser, Points) values ('$id','$points')"; 

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo "Successfully Registered";
    }
    else{
        echo "Could not register"; 
    }
}
else{
    echo 'error de conexion';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: ok, i will try. Do you see anything more wrong o this could fix it?

Comment: untill now thats the error i can see, hope this will work everything out

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){  //that's get method
  $id = $_POST['id']; // here you are getting value from $_POST
```

It should be `$_GET`

Comment: ok, i will try. Do you see anything more wrong o this could fix it?

Answer (score 0):

change this

*$id = $_POST['id'];
$points = $_POST['points'];*

to this,

*$id = $_GET['id'];
$points = $_GET['points'];*

Comment: ok, i will try. Do you see anything more wrong o this could fix it?